# How to create a scatter plot for each dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to write some code in order to create an animation of scatter plot data through tine. In order to do this I have a dataset with multiple columns where each column represents a numbered timestep.

I would like the code to cycle through each timestep column for the y axis and use a constant x axis, so that a separate scatter plot is generated for each timestep. I tried to do this by coding a for loop that specifies an incrementing column number for the y axis.

My current code generates three out of seven scatter plots in my sample data but returns the following error:

`IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9`

I have tried other similar solutions on stack overflow but that didn't correct my problem.

The data is here if anyone wants to use what I am using: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7vwa0lud44td2ak/test_splot_anim_noTS.csv?dl=0[data file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7vwa0lud44td2ak/test_splot_anim_noTS.csv?dl=0)

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas a pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data=pd.read_csv("test_splot_anim_noTS.csv") 

for n in range (6, 13):
    data.plot(kind='scatter', x='metres', y=n)
    plt.ylim(-4,4)
    plt.savefig('n.jpeg')
```

Answer (score 0):

## `panda.DataFrame.plot`, single line plot

```
data=pd.read_csv("test_splot_anim_noTS.csv")
data.set_index('metres', drop=True, inplace=True)
data.plot()
```

[image]

## With `matplotlib`, single plot with all columns:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(data)
plt.show()
```

## Separate scatter plots, files saved:

```
for col in data.columns:
    plt.scatter(data.index, data[col])
    plt.ylim(-4, 4)
    plt.savefig(f'{col}.jpeg')
    plt.show()
```

## With Seaborn:

```
for col in data.columns:
    sns.scatterplot(data.index, data[col])
    plt.ylim(-4,4)
    plt.savefig(f'{col}.jpeg')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 data=pd.read_csv("test_splot_anim_noTS.csv")
 for column in data.columns[1:]:
     data.plot(kind='scatter', x='metres',y=column)
     plt.ylim(-4,4)
     plt.savefig('{}.jpeg'.format(column))
```

I may have done it!